# Postfix send clear error on retired domains?

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix

I've retired a few domain names and removed them from my server. Because the DNS NS records now point to a nonexisting DNS server a user sending an email to the retired domain name will not get an error back.

I would like those users should at least get an error back, so I pointed the NS record of retired domain to my DNS server and added MX record to my mail server. In file

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf
```

I did **not** add the retired domain to the "mydestination =" line.

Now when user sends an email to retired domain he gets a

```
Relay access denied error
```

I do get this relay error because the username is still valid (I use 1 username for all my domains), only the domainname is not valid anymore (actually not supported by postfix in this case).

Is it possible to return something similar to "`user not found`" or "`domain not found`"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my initial thinking that i wouldn't get an error when sending email to a domain with a invalid NS records was wrong. After about a day you get a email similar to :

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

     mail@mail.com

Technical details of permanent failure:
DNS Error: xxxxx DNS type 'mx' lookup of mail.com responded with code NXDOMAIN
Domain name not found: mail.com
```

or:

```
This is an automatically generated Delivery Status Notification.

Unable to deliver message to the following recipients, due to being unable to connect successfully to the destination mail server.

       mail@mail.com
```

When the email is send depends on the mail server that is sending your email. Some seem to quit trying after about 12 hours some take up to 24 hours.